# 'at' not working on Kubuntu[Linux]

Tags: linux

I'm new to Linux. And I tried using the at command to echo "Hello" after 2 minutes and I saw the following.

-$ at now + 2 minutes
-at> echo "Hello"
-at> `<EOT>` 
job 7 at Tue Aug  9 23:59:00 2011

So far it hasn't worked. I'm trying to get used to the syntax. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`at` is a funny little beast. Its default behaviour is to mail you whatever the output was to stdout or stderr. Redirecting its output is an annoying business that works intermittently depending on the system.

If you want to play with `at`, I'd recommend finding a program to start or stop, or write a script and throw the output to a text file like so:

```
at -m -f script.sh now + 2 minutes > outfile.txt  2>&1
```

Don't forget the `2>&1` at the end; it redirects stdout and stderr.

Your syntax is correct, so that isn't the problem -- the problem here is with `at`.